# How to show Loader when a API is in process? React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Approach I used:

I create a **single** Redux State ' **API_IN_PROCESS** ' which is set to TRUE if any API is called and to FALSE when it gives Response.

Based on its state, I show SPINNER/LOADER on the Pages.

Issue I'm facing is:

If I have two separate API calls on PAGE-1 and PAGE-2. And if either one of it gets called, the loader shows on both the pages as its using 1 State ( API_IN_PROCESS ) to show a SPINNER/LOADER

I don't want to create separate states like this ( API_ONE_IN_PROCESS ) and ( API_TWO_IN_PROCESS ) because ones the project grows It may have 10s of pages and its not perfect to handle this issue.

Looking for a solution where the spinner is shown only in specific page where API is called.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can add one more state called `EngagedPageIndex` and update it when a page is engaged with API by page index (or identifier). So, you can control the Spinner/Loader by checking both of `API_IN_PROCESS` and `EngagedPageIndex` states for each page.